# Components not returning inside flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, map-function

Was trying to conditionally return items in a flatlist but it is not returning anything in react native.
Thanks in advance

```
<FlatList
              data={posts}
              ref={(c) => {this.flatList = c;}}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              renderItem={({item}) => {
                  item.categories_name.map(category=>{
                    let cat = category.toLowerCase();
                    if(cat=='movie'){
                      <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'white'}}>This is movie</Text>
                    }
                    else(
                       <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'white'}}>This is normal post</Text>
                      )
                    }
                  })
                  //<PostItem onImagePress={()=>this.toggleModal(item.id)} route={this.state.route_name} post={item}/>
                }
              }
              />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you re-arrange your code to the following?

```
<FlatList
          data={posts}
          ref={c => {
            this.flatList = c;
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            let views = [];
            item.categories_name.map(category => {
              let cat = category.toLowerCase();
              if (cat == "movie") {
                views.push(
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "white" }}>
                    This is movie
                  </Text>
                );
              } else {
                views.push(
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "white" }}>
                    This is normal post
                  </Text>
                );
              }
            });
            return views;
            //<PostItem onImagePress={()=>this.toggleModal(item.id)} route={this.state.route_name} post={item}/>
          }}
        />
```

Comment: You are amazing brother. Thank you soo much

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the JSX elements when using renderItem.

when you see `renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}`. It is the shorthand of:

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
    return <Text>{item.key}</Text>
}}
```

So something like below should work:

```
<FlatList
  data={posts}
  ref={(c) => {this.flatList = c;}}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  renderItem={({item}) => {
    return item.categories_name.map(category=>{
      let cat = category.toLowerCase();
      if(cat=='movie'){
        return <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'white'}}>This is movie</Text>
      } else {
        return <Text style={{fontSize:20,color:'white'}}>This is normal post</Text>
      }
    })
    ...
```

*You should notice above that renderItem `returns` whatever `.map` returns (which should be an array of JSX elements. This `return` inside .map fn is also necessary: `return <Text style...` because that's how you want to use `.map`, *you want to return array of elements* If that is not so clear please check `.map` and figure that out on your own. That should help you better*

I hope this helps